# How to check if mouseclick is in an area

Tags: c++, opengl

Ok So I have a few images I am putting on a screen, Really all you would need to know is each glvertex2f() is a point, thus 4 points connected is an area. Each glVertex2f is created by and X,Y .  I would like to save this area range so when i do a mouse click and get the x,y result,  I can test to see if the mouseclick x,y is inside this area.

So here is where i create the area

```
for( int z = 0; z < 6; z++ )
{
if( game->player1.Blockbestand[z] > 0 )
{
    glLoadIdentity();               
    xoff = (z/4.0f);
    yoff = (floor(xoff))/4.0f;

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0/4 + xoff,0/4 + yoff);       glVertex2f( x1,game->camera.height-y1);
    glTexCoord2f(0/4 + xoff,1.0/4 + yoff);    glVertex2f( x2,game->camera.height-y1 );
    glTexCoord2f(1.0/4 + xoff,1.0/4 + yoff); glVertex2f( x2,game->camera.height-y2 );
    glTexCoord2f(1.0/4 + xoff,0/4 + yoff);    glVertex2f( x1,game->camera.height-y2 );
    glEnd();

    x1= x2+10;
    x2 = x1+30;
    xoff = (z/4.0f);
    yoff = (floor(xoff))/4.0f;  
}
}
```

and here is where i get the mouse click

```
for (std::list<MouseState>::iterator it = clicks->begin(); it != clicks->end(); it++) {
    if (it->leftButton == true){
        std::cout << "Left click!\n";
        std::cout << "x: " << it->x << "\n";
            std::cout << "y: " << it->y << "\n";
    }

}
```

So i assume i can save the area in an array somehow.  and then when ever a leftbutton click is true , i get the x, y  and look in the array to see if its in the area.. but no clue how to do this..

Comment: check this out
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3097/Mouse-Selection-in-OpenGL-Scene

Comment: I was trying to get away from that, as its been outdated to use select mode.   I know my new way is not the best but for a simple procedure i needed it for it would work great also not sure opengl tag is a good call for this.. as i expect it to be done in c++ no opengl needed. i know glVertex is open gl but still its more of an equation of area question

Comment: if it helps...  Say i have x=1 y=6 , x=5 y=6 , x=5 y=3, x=1 y=3 .. Then if i click x=2 , y=4  then i have clicked in this area because x is between 5 and 1 and y is between 6 and 3.  Thus i would have to seach a whole array and see if my mouse click x/y  fits any of those.

Comment: Yes, that's right. You would check your mouse coordinates against the bounding box of each of your images. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: how you do it,  how to search the array that would hold all the xy coords,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the 4 points in an array

```
locationCheck[m][n] = x1;
locationCheck[m][n+1] = x2;
locationCheck[m][n+2] = game->camera.height-y1;
locationCheck[m][n+3] = game->camera.height-y2;


m++;
```

then check if the x/y of mouse is between the 4 points like so.

```
void GameScreen::menuClickCheck(int x,int y){
int m = 0;
int n=0;
while (m < 32){
    if (locationCheck[m][n] < x && locationCheck[m][n+1] > x) 
        if (locationCheck[m][n+2] > y && locationCheck[m][n+3] < y)
            {
            switch (m)
            {
                case 0 : cout << "Type=DefaultLand \n";
                break;
                case 1 : cout << "Type=Lava \n";
                break;
                case 2 : cout << "Type=Stone \n";
                break;


            }//end switch
        m=32;
    }//endif
    m++;
}//whileloop

}
```